# measured time mismatch in running curl in parallel

Tags: curl, time, gnu-parallel

I want to measure time taken by individual curl command and also total time taken by set of curl commands running in parallel, However I could see mismatch between these two numbers as follows

```
time seq 2 | parallel -n0 "curl -o /dev/null -s -w %{time_total}\\n -x http://mywebsite"
```

I could see following output
curl 1- 1.828647
curl 2- 1.894729
total time printed by 'time'
real    0m2.034s
user    0m0.267s
sys     0m0.332s

if I add up curl 1 and curl 2 times is not equal to 'real' time printed by 'time' command. could you explain why they are not same?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it is easier to understand with a simpler example:

```
$ time seq 2 | time parallel --tag time sleep
1
1       real    0m1.037s
1       user    0m0.000s
1       sys     0m0.030s
2
2       real    0m2.032s
2       user    0m0.015s
2       sys     0m0.000s

(parallel)
0.24user 0.25system 0:02.59elapsed 19%CPU (0avgtext+0avgdata 233104maxresident)k
0inputs+0outputs (60960major+0minor)pagefaults 0swaps

(seq)
real    0m2.631s
user    0m0.260s
sys     0m0.290s
```

The total time is > 2s but it is not 3s because `sleep 1` and `sleep 2` run in parallel.